# Expanding Jdeveloper for BPEL Process

Tags: jdeveloper, bpel

I have installed JDeveloper. No I need to extend it for BPEL process. I have pcbpel_bundle.zip. how will I add it in to Jdeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to specify which version of `JDeveloper` you are using. If it is 11g, you can add `BPEL` component by adding a jar file for `SOA` extension which you can find either by checking for updates in JDev or manually adding a jar file in extensions. You can download this jar from http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/156082.xml

If it is 12c, you have installation problems because 12c comes along with `SOA` components(in-built support).